# Export node-red flow to script

Tags: node.js, node-red, odb

I'm looking ways to export Node-Red flow to script. This way I could make some ODBC integrations for my software and export them to one script.

Is this possible? If not, is there any scaling issues to use one node-red with differnt ODBC databases?

Answer (score 1):

No, Node-RED does not do code generation, you can not export a flow to be a standalone application/script.

The second half of your question is not clear. You can add as many nodes connecting to databases as you want, how this scales will very much depend on what exactly you are doing with each of these databases and what rate you pass messages through the system.